# Confusion about the continuity equation for incompressible fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, flow

Consider that water, a perfect incompressible fluid, flow through the section  $S_B$ of a cylindrical container with section $S$ and height $H$: figure (reference: "Jean Jacques Meister, exercices, fluides, Ecole Polytechnique Fédérale de Lausanne"). This container is opened at the top (not as in the figure). I would like to apply continuity equation. For me to do so, we have to chose a volume $\Omega$ of fluid that is contained in a **fixed** surface $\Sigma$. For example a surface around the sound the cylinder which bottom at the bottom of the cylinder and top at $H/2$. Here, I would choose $\Sigma$ to be the container. Then, I would have :
$$\int_{\Sigma}\vec{J_m} \cdot \vec{d\sigma}=\int_{\text{section B}}\rho \vec{v}\cdot \vec{d\sigma}=\rho v_BS_B$$
since no fluid enters the surface, the only thing that is happening is fluid going out of the surface through the section $B$. $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the fluid, $\vec{J_m}$ the mass density of the fluid and $\rho$ its density. But, the solution states that : 
$$v_AS=v_BS_B$$ and I don't understand this. Is it possible to apply the continuity equation on a surface $\Sigma$ which surround all the considered fluid, and which is **moving with the fluid**?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed have to consider a **fixed spatial volume** $V$ contained in a set of boundaries $\Sigma$. For steady-state flow and an incompressible fluid the [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Integral_form) degenerates to the given term but there are **two fluxes over the surface** that need to be considered, one entering the control volume in $S_A$ and one exiting it in $S_B$. As for the integral conservation equations the normal vectors $\vec n_i$ are assumed to be pointing outwards of the considered control volume this results in a positive and a negative flux that in sum have to cancel out as there are no sources of mass in the control volume.

$$\int\limits_\Sigma \underbrace{\vec J_m}_{\rho \vec u} \cdot d \vec n = \int\limits_{S_A} \rho \vec u \cdot d \vec n_A + \int\limits_{S_B} \rho \vec u \cdot d \vec n_B = - \rho u_A S_A + \rho u_B S_B \overset{!}{=} 0$$

That there must indeed also be an incoming flux in $S_A$ can easily be seen when considering that for a liquid column of finite height after some time the surrounding gas would enter the control volume.

Comment: but here you suppose that $A$ does not move ? What is the control volume that you choose ?

Comment: @Dicordi I assumed your spatially fixed control volume, a cylinder with height $\frac{H}{2}$, and only looked at the fluxes through all the surfaces. The surrounding walls allow no mass fluxes though it but flow might exit through the surface $S_B$ and enter through $S_A$.

Comment: @Dicordi If you would drain the container completely you would notice that water is flowing out of $S_B$ with an average velocity $u_B$ and the water surface would move downwards with a velocity $u_A$ (in fact no matter which control volume you take). As the fluid can't be compressed $\rho = const$ everything exiting the volume has to enter it somewhere.

Comment: Ok that is now clear for me ! Because we can consider that the velocity of the fluid in the cylinder is the same on a current line, the velocity of the fluid that goes in the fixed volume is $v_A$.